# How to async httpwebrequest and thread

Tags: c#

I am trying to async httpwebrequest for 3 days i trying every thing First My code is

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest0_1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("dir.com" + "/access_token.json");
httpWebRequest0_1.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
httpWebRequest0_1.KeepAlive = true;
httpWebRequest0_1.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
httpWebRequest0_1.Headers.Add(this.string_6, string_5);
```

I want to send async request each time but my CPU and RAM usage 100% And my async Method is

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 5).ToList().ForEach(f =>
{
    new Thread(() =>
    {   
        method_6();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }).Start();
});
```

I want to send request for 1 sec each time.

Comment: put the sleep in the foreach section not as part of the thread

Comment: This block my UI

Comment: then dont run that function on the UI then

Comment: Backgroundworker Good choice?

Comment: _"Backgroundworker Good choice"_ Nope. Use Task/async/await.

Comment: For thread? or http..

Comment: Async all the way, always (mostly).

Comment: Its not easy :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the limited snippet in question, I'd suggest using TAP as follows:

```
async Task RequestAsync()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    {
        await method_6();
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
}
```

Assuming `method_6` is doing the webrequest, it would have to be changed:

```
async Task method_6()
{
     // Create WebRequest httpWebRequest0_1  like in question

     await httpWebRequest0_1.GetResponseAsync();
}
```